# Pip install --upgrade results in unexpected version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install external Python program to virtual environment using `Pip` version `21.0.1` on Ubuntu.

I use command `pip install --upgrade hg+https://example.com/app1/@CHANGESET#egg=app1`. This seems to work when I install `app1` to clean virtual environment. But if I try to change version off `app1` Pip does not install version I expect. I am using the `--upgrade` flag so I belive it should be possible to change version without uninstalling previous version first.

I install version `1.0` of `app1` using Mercurial tags. Pip reports correct version after installation.

```
pip install --upgrade hg+https://example.com/app1/@1.0#egg=app1
pip freeze
app1==1.0
```

Then I try to upgrade to newer changeset.

```
pip install --upgrade hg+https://example.com/app1/@CHANGESET#egg=app1
Collecting app1
  Cloning hg https://example.com/app1/ (to revision CHANGESET) to /tmp/pip-install-4398yh34/app1_...
  Running command hg clone --noupdate -q https://example.com/app1/ /tmp/pip-install-4398yh34/app1_...
  Running command hg update -q CHANGESET
```

The command completes succesfully but `pip freeze` still reports version as `1.0` instead of requested changeset. Checking files in `virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/app1` shows that they are of version 1.0 and not from requested changeset.

Same problem happens if try to upgrade to older changeset.

If add flag `-e` to Pip command I am able to change package version without this problem.
But why `--upgrade` is no enough and why command completes without errors while results are not what they should be?

Comment: what's the version in `setup.py` for the `CHANGESET` revision?  my bet is it's still 1.0

Comment: @AnthonySottile Correct, turns out `setup.py` still has version 1.0 in `CHANGESET`.

Comment: makes sense then, 1.0 and 1.0 are the same so no upgrade